# Devise registration confirmation email delivered 20 minutes late + What delivery method does Devise mailer use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, actionmailer, devise-invitable

I have two problems I have been wasting a lot of time on for the past 3 days. I would really appreciate experienced coders helping me out here,.

I have a model `User` that I send a confirmation email using Devise invitable from the registration controller.

```
User.invite!({:email => email, ...)
```

Now I have these settings

**In config/environments/development.rb**

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address:              'mail.myapp.com',
      port:                  26, 
      domain:               'myapp.com',
      user_name:            'notifications@myapp.com',
      password:             'xxxx',
      authentication:       'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto:  true,
      openssl_verify_mode:   'none'
  }
```

and **config/devise.rb**

```
config.mailer_sender = 'notifications@myapp.com'
```

This mail is delivered exactly 20 minutes later after the debug output says "Sent email to ..."

Now I also use a custom NotificationsMailer else where in the code, where I send notification emails other than the devise based registration process. I have the same settings as above entered in `config/initializers/setup_mail.rb` and **in this case**, the mails are delivered instantaneously.Why this delay?

**Question/doubt #2**
I figured if I could intercept the delivery process of sending the mail, I would be able to check the Mail::Message object through logging and later develop an asynchronous way of handling using Sidekiq.

So in **config/application.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :queued, :QueuedDelivery
```

**In config/environments/development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :queued
```

In **lib/queued_delivery.rb**

```
class QueuedDelivery
  def deliver!(mail)
    logger.debug "mail object string rep: #{mail.to_s}"
    logger.debug "mail object settings: #{mail.deliver_method.settings}"
  end
end
```

In spite of changing the delivery method, it's weird Devise still sends the mail which arrives 20 minutes late as usual and I cant see the debug level logging that I put above. 
**How is Devise sending these emails?!** I checked `devise_mail()` in the devise gem, and it uses this code finally `mail headers_for(action, opts)`. What is going on here?

Comment: Maybe to help clear things up: is the "instant" mail and the "delayed" mail sent to the same email address?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same address to test these features